# Creating a Select drop down menu for marker on Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have created some simple maps following the Google API tutorials.
The code used is shown below with only two markers in the array, but more are used.
As some markers are close together on the map I would like to read the markers into a select / option drop down menu so markers can be selected by name "cave:" in the array in addition to being able to click on the markers.. I have not been able to find a way to do this as yet. Is this possible?

Also is there a way to close the previous infowindow when a new one is opened?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    var markers = [
    { lat: 51.589994, lng: -4.112497, cave: "Cat Hole Cave", name: "<h2>Cat Hole Cave</h2><img src='http://www.ogof.org.uk/Pictures/Entrances/1118.jpg' width='200' height='150'><br><h3><A href='http://www.cambriancavingcouncil.org.uk/registry/ccr_registry_view.php?ID=1118' target=_blank>Cambrian Cave Registry Entry</A><br><br>SS 53757 90020<br>Altitude 51m<br>Length 30m</h3>", site: "blue_cave.png"},
    { lat: 51.564564, lng: -4.274611, cave: "Mewslade Quarry Cave - Left", name: "<h2>Mewslade Quarry Cave - Left Entrance</h2><img src='http://www.ogof.org.uk/Pictures/Entrances/1570.jpg' width='200' height='150'><br><h3><A href='http://www.cambriancavingcouncil.org.uk/registry/ccr_registry_view.php?ID=1570' target=_blank>Cambrian Cave Registry Entry</A><br><br>SS 42440 87530<br>Altitude TBCm<br>Length 10m<br><br>Photo courtesy of Gary Evans</h3>", site: "blue_cave.png" },
];

for (index in markers) addMarker(markers[index]);
function addMarker(data) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
    map: map,
    title: data.cave,
    icon: data.site
  });     
  var content = document.createElement("DIV");
  var title = document.createElement("DIV");
  title.innerHTML = data.name;
  content.appendChild(title);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: content,
  maxWidth: 180
    });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (index in markers) {
      var data = markers[index];
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Here is a link to the page as it works at the moment. 
http://www.ogof.org.uk/Gower-Cave-Location-Map.html

Comment: one idea is to check distance between markers, and comparing to zoom determine if they are close to each other. if yes, show only one marker with dropdown in info window that will change zoom and will show all markers at that position.

Comment: That will help somewhat, but a clickable list with names of each marker location is needed to help finding specific markers.

Comment: Look for examples with a clickable sidebar like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html) or [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html).  The sidebar links can easily be changed to a dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion @geocodezip. I have now reworked the page replacing the side bar with drop down menu. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. [updated page](http://ogof.org.uk/Gower-Cave-Location-Map.html)